# Magento - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in … Fulltext.php on line 93

Tags: magento, exception, magento-1.7

I’m trying to help a friend out with his installation of Magento (v1.7.0.2).

He can’t update any of his CMS pages, and the exception logs always shows the above error. When trying to Reindex the pages, the same error occurs as well.

Here’s the log for trying to save a page:

```
2014-05-21T09:30:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php on line 93
Trace: #0 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/wildgu...', 93, Array)
#1 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php(184): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext->_regenerateStoreIndex('1', '11')
#2 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Fulltext.php(40): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext->regenerateIndex(NULL, '11')
#3 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Observer.php(44): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Fulltext->regenerateIndex(NULL, '11')
#4 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Observer->regenerateCmsPageIndex(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Observer), 'regenerateCmsPa...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('cms_page_save_a...', Array)
#7 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('cms_page_save_a...', Array)
#8 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#9 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php(150): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Cms_PageController->saveAction()
#11 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#12 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(223): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Here’s the log for Reindexing:

```
2014-05-21T09:20:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php on line 93
Trace: #0 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/wildgu...', 93, Array)
#1 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php(184): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext->_regenerateStoreIndex('1', NULL)
#2 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Fulltext.php(40): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Mysql4_Fulltext->regenerateIndex(NULL, NULL)
#3 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Observer.php(44): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Fulltext->regenerateIndex(NULL, NULL)
#4 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Observer.php(107): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Observer->regenerateCmsPageIndex(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Observer->catalogsearchIndexProcessStart(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete_Model_Observer), 'catalogsearchIn...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalogsearch_i...', Array)
#8 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Fulltext.php(82): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalogsearch_i...', Array)
#9 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(446): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext->rebuildIndex()
#10 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#14 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#15 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(223): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /var/www/wildguitars.co.il/htdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error states, there is an invalid argument supplied for foreach in a file, which is a part of MageWorx_SearchAutocomplete module. The only way to know is to debug into that file ( app/code/local/MageWorx/SearchAutocomplete/Model/Mysql4/Fulltext.php on line 93 ) and make sure the foreach gets an appropriate variable. Check [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) docs.

Comment: Clearly my question is specifically for Magento and the issues caused by that. I could edit the PHP file to "fix" it, but that would be pointless for this specific since its a pre-coded system and not my own.

Comment: all im saying it is easy to tell the reason, if you debug into the module

Comment: Why bother when there are probably other people using it? This isn't a PHP question, its a Magento question as far as I'm concerned. I'm appreciate your will to help anyways. Thanks.